# ¿Como inserto el ID del usuario de mi sesion y lo agrego a mi BD?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, datatables

Tengo lo siguiente y quiero subir mi id_usuario de la sesion pero no me da nada.

```
if ($resultado) {
    $idReporte = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($arregloIds); $i++) {
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO pedidos_reportes(id_usuario, id_reporte, id_pedido, fecha_modificacion) VALUES ( '$_SESSION['id_usuario']' , '$idReporte','$arregloIds[$i]', now() ) ";
        $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta); // No puedo pasar el ID de sesion.
    }
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias. :)

Comment: Enviar el ID del usuario via AJAX, POST, GET, etc. es MUY mala idea... ¿que evita que modifiquen este dato a mano?

Comment: Lo más usado es almacenar el ID del usuario en la sesión, de donde puedes obtenerlo cada vez que hace falta. Si ya lo tienes allí, simplemente invócalo, si no, habría que ver como funciona tu  _sesión de usuario_, por ejemplo, qué y dónde almacenas información de quién inició sesión (del lado del servidor, obviamente).

Comment: Ya le asigne una variable, y no la reconoce, edite mi publicación gracias por la ayuda